# zeep Client throws UnicodeDecodeError utf-8 codec can't decode byte

Tags: python, soap, encoding, zeep

On linux I try to write a program which connects to a windows-SOAP-service (maybe the OS is important in context of that issue).

I connect to this service with:

```
class GWS:
   def __init__:
       self.config = configparser.ConfigParser()
       self.config.read(join(os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__)), "configuration.ini"))
       self.gClient = zeep.Client(wsdl=self.config["G"]["g_wsdl_url"])
...
```

Than I try to call a service like

```
...
self.gWS = GWS()
self.gService = self.gWS.gClient.service
...
arf = self.g.GetAbrResultFiles(tfile.DT_ID, self.s.secret)
```

The last line than throws errors i.e.:
"UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xff in position 0: invalid start byte" or "UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xd9 in position 4: invalid continuation byte
", but byte-value and position may differ.

I tried to "decode('ISO-1252-1')" or "decode('utf-8')", but with no luck.

Anyone an idea, whats the problem here?

Comment: I'd guess that _`0xff` in position 0_ means that the first two bytes are `0xff`, `0xfe` i.e. [byte order mark](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark#UTF-16) UTF16LE…